# simple php websocket example

Tags: php, html, websocket

Could someone please give me simple websocket code.

I am creating websocket example but it's not working fine and I don't know what's the problem.

Thanks.

examples: [server-side](http://20xi.com/server.php.txt) and [client-side](http://20xi.com/client.html.text).

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: check it on http://www.20xi.com/server.php.txt for server side and http://www.20xi.com/client.html.text for client side

Comment: @Allex: Those links aren't working. Edit your post to include the code.

Comment: that's a lot of code to read with the only information "its not working" you are going to have to be more specific than that.

Comment: if you have any easy program to send message to server using websocket then please send me link

Comment: you would have to let us know what you are using as the client side. i have a PHP socket server i use for a Flash app. connects with ActionScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at the source here:
http://www.dwalker.co.uk/source_code/nav.html?phpjobscheduler_3.5/pjsfiles/functions.php.source.html

from line 310 it shows how to connect using both CURL and
FSOCKOPEN

Hope that helps...

Comment: can you give me working example of this modified or written by you ?